# JSON Object as string for @Input - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am having a component's html in which I have a property called **info** which is referred in a service file. The problem is info is a json string which will be parsed in the service (by angular). I have a scenario where one of the values of json contains a quote ('). The problem is I am unable to bypass the quote in html without running into a compilation error. Is there any solution for the same?

The following is an example snippet

```
<my-component id="wt_tab_206_000000010wrap" class="form-group  inlineblock"
                    [info]="{'id':'wt_tab_206_000000010','value':'LoadDatanew','disabled':false,'readonly':false}"
                    filterFields="N"></my-component>
```

In the above example, `[info]` is the property of concern. In that the value key is supposed to have the value like `LoadData'new`. But parsing it like `LoadData\'new` is not solving the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How come `LoadData\'new` is not solving it? That should definitely work.

Comment: Try with `LoadData\\\'new`

Comment: @Wazeed `LoadData\\\'new` is getting parsed as `LoadData\'new` Thats the weird part!!

Comment: With a single \ should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data as a object without stringifying it.

Just pass it like this:

```
<my-component id="wt_tab_206_000000010wrap" class="form-group inlineblock"
                    [info]="obj"
                    filterFields="N">
</my-component>
```

In your `.ts` file:

```
public obj = {
  id: 'wt_tab_206_000000010',
  value: 'LoadDatanew',
  disabled: false,
  readonly: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would like to know if there is a way to handle it in the html file directly

Comment: That's not JSON, but a generic structure of type `Object` in JavaScript.

Comment: there are ways line encode and decode but it is a waste of time because you increase the process and make it harder for yourself to update the data if it's needed @KrishnaPrashatt